# "Mathjax is not defined" JavaScript error and no toolbar is shown and preview doesn't work

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown-preview

Currently if I try to open https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask and ask a question in Firefox or Chrome the preview won't work. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

You see, there's no text in the preview area, no toolbar and there's a "Mathjax not defined" error message in the JavaScript console. Firefox console shows the same error message.

Comment: Looks like it is a wider problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133611/mathjax-is-not-defined-javascript-error-and-no-toolbar-is-shown-and-preview-do

Comment: norepo on chrom with windows 7 for me.

Comment: @Kortuk: I guess it is specific to user location. Perhaps some network problem. Anyway not being able to load Mathjax should not break the toolbar and the preview.

Comment: @sharptooth - I can't reproduce it here.  Are you behind a proxy or something like that?  Good point, though, about needing a graceful degradation if MathJax won't load.

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer: I'm behind Microsoft ISA Server, but this has been here for ages and these problems with MathJax only started today. I guess it is something network-related - maybe the CDN can't serve requests from my network or something like that.

Comment: @sharptooth, I was not trying to imply you were not having the issue, just quickly adding information for anyone that might be debugging it. A while back imgur had issues that just caused Europe to not be able to load images. I hope it gets resolved.

Comment: @Kortuk: Yes, I realize that, I just provide the details I can think of. Still not having graceful degradation is a problem - any third-party service can become temporarily unavailable and it shouldn't have that much effect.

Comment: Any progress on this @sharptooth?

Comment: @Kortuk: I found it's specific to my computer. So I guess it's some environment problem. I created this feature request http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133824/132564 to make the interface degrade only partially.

Comment: @sharptooth, Well I guess I will flag this status-repo for now then if it is specific. scratch that, status no-repo means it is either fixed for all users or determined no repo by dev team. I cannot flag it that unless your problem is resolved.